# Error 503 with my .jar after transfer my website to an other hoster

Tags: java, httprequest, http-status-code-503

I created a minecraft launcher with SKCraft and everything was hosted on 000webhost.com. Then I transferred my site to hostinger.com and changed all the links to point to my new host.

Except that since, I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Did not get expected response code, got 503 for https://ragnaguys.hostingerapp.com/latest.json
    at com.skcraft.launcher.bootstrap.HttpRequest.expectResponseCode(HttpRequest.java:154)
    at com.skcraft.launcher.bootstrap.Downloader.execute(Downloader.java:74)
    at com.skcraft.launcher.bootstrap.Downloader.run(Downloader.java:42)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Only the URL of the file has changed in my code and the link is functional from a browser.

Is there anything I need to change in the server configuration? Since on the program side nothing changed except the link.

Everything works fine if I put the links back to 000wewhost.com

Thanks!

Comment: Please check if https://ragnaguys.hostingerapp.com/latest.json is accessible from a incognito browser.